# create function with dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have this work and need do it by only changing var1 and var2. So, I would like to create function but I could not. Can you make function with this simple work?

```
a12 = data %>%  group_by(var1,var2)%>% tally 
a12_1 <- data %>% group_by(var1) %>% tally
a12_2 = merge(a12,a12_1,by="var1")
a12_2$perc = a12_2[,3] / a12_2[,4]
```

The challenging for me is how to deal with this argument while creating function.

```
a_fun <- function(data,var1,var2)
```

Comment: You might want to show input, desired output and words explaining their connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're struggling with the non-standard evaluation, if you append `_` to the dplyr functions you can pass strings as arguments. I've not tested it, but you could try:

```
a_fun <- function(data, var1, var2) {
    a12 <- data %>% group_by_(var1, var2) %>% tally()
    a12_1 <- data %>% group_by_(var1) %>% tally()
    a12_2 <- merge(a12, a12_1, by = var1)
    a12_2$perc <- a12_2[, 3] / a12_2[, 4]
    return(a12_2)
}
```

e.g

```
a_fun(data, "col1", "col2")
```

Comment: `group_by_()` is deprecated. Use `group_by()` instead. To pass strings as arguments one can do `group_by(!! enquo(var1))`. More info [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).